# .NET MVC 5 InvalidOperationException: IDX10803

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

I recently finished building the application and it has always worked when running from Visual Studio. I've now published to IIS 8 and am using apps.dev.microsoft.com for the registration with Azure AD.

I am able to connect to the home page of my application but whenever I press my login button to bring me to log in for getting access to the user account for Microsoft Graph it does "waiting for host" and eventually times out. The following is my error:

```
[TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.]
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +167
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.<GetDocumentAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +286

[IOException: Unable to get document from: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration]
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.<GetDocumentAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +589
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.<GetAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +294
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) +25
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.<GetConfigurationAsync>d__3.MoveNext() +1246

[InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable to create to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'.]
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.<GetConfigurationAsync>d__3.MoveNext() +1833
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.<ApplyResponseChallengeAsync>d__c.MoveNext() +575
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<ApplyResponseCoreAsync>d__b.MoveNext() +282
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<ApplyResponseAsync>d__8.MoveNext() +275
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<TeardownAsync>d__5.MoveNext() +160
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +815
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +182
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +638
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +182
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext() +180
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +69
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +64
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar) +156
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +9775336

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2623.0
```

I would also note that the ASP .NET version at the bottom reads `4.7.2623`, I'm on 4.5, not sure why it would show 4.7 as I don't have 4.7 installed on IIS.

Comment: .NET 4.7 is the version of .NET Framework installed on the server, you cannot install it nor select it on IIS. That said, the problem is a networking one and we cannot help you with that. The application is being blocked access to the endpoint `login.microsoftonline.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Camilo Terevinto commented, this is a connectivity issue between your app and login.microsoftonline.com.
You may be behind a firewall that blocks the connection for example.

The error itself is quite clear, it is unable to download the metadata document that it requires to perform authentication correctly.
This document contains the URL from which the app downloads the public signing keys used by Azure AD to sign tokens for example.
Without those keys, the app cannot validate the user identity.

Comment: Okay, that's really not what I wanted to hear.. lol. Maybe there are IIS people that can give more insight because every firewall has been disabled, I have a hard time believing it's a networking config. issue at this point. Maybe I'm wrong.. has to be something configured wrong elsewhere in my opinion at this point. I'll keep trying things.

Comment: Shall bite my words on this one, marked as correct answer. Got it working. Thanks.